# Adding Author Metadata to a TXT or CFG file

Tags: metadata, config, author

Basically I am looking for a way of "branding" a cfg file. Specifically a CSGO-config, so yes, nothing too important. I'm just surprised, that after quite a bit of google search, I still havent found anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, plain text files (and probably .cfg files) do not contain any metadata by default. The file system should keep track of some properties for these file types, but they won't otherwise transfer across filesystems.

If you would like to "brand" your file, perhaps you could add a comment to the top with your name. It would be about as permanent and immutable as any metadata anyways.